# warning message from cron

Tags: cron

This morning I started receiving a warning message from my regular cron job.

```
Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in /home/customer/www/crm.coma.org/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory-master/subscriptionhistory.civix.php on line 149+
```

I haven't knowlingly changed anything or even used CiviCRM this morning. I don't suppose it matters much, but I'm curious. CiviCRM 5.35.1 WordPress 5.7.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a php 7.4 warning. The extension org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory needs to make the change in the extension and then they should release a new version. I would post an issue there: https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/org.cpehn.subscriptionhistory/issues

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. I've got php set to automatically update by my hosting provider, so I expect that is the change that started this message. Not sure why a scheduled job would use this extension, but I'll take that up with the author when reporting.

Comment: @Jon G - Megaphone Tech has fixed it, but as he says it will affect other extensions and now another is causing the same message!

Comment: It was mentioned in the [dev-digest in April](https://lists.civicrm.org/lists/arc/civicrm-dev/2021-04/msg00000.html) (about 1/3 way down) but yes there are lots of extensions it affects. It may take authors some time to get to them all but you can always post an issue. And oh just wait until php 8 - there's going to be lots more warnings.